# How to set a notification at a particular time so that it will notify user to provide feedback

Tags: android, android-notifications, ratingbar

I have 2 activity class, Main Activity & Rating Bar Activity. I have a broadcast receiver class as MyReceiver. I have set the time as 20:00 or i change according to the system time just to receive the notification, but i am not getting any notification nor any error in logcat. Please suggest what needs to be done. Below are my classes:

MainActivity:

```
 package com.myapp.priya.employeeapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RatingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intentResult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                intentResult,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }


}
```

RatingBar:`

```
package com.myapp.priya.employeeapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);

        final RatingBar simpleRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get values and then displayed in a toast
                String totalStars = "Total Stars:: " + simpleRatingBar.getNumStars();
                String rating = "Rating :: " + String.valueOf(simpleRatingBar.getRating());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), totalStars + "\n" + rating, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }




}
`
```

MyReceiver:

```
 package com.myapp.priya.employeeapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Created by priya on 09-08-2017.
 */

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int MID = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,RatingActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    /*.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.employee_opinion_surveys)*/
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setContentTitle("HR Feedback")
                .setContentText("Please provide the feedback");
        manager.notify(MID,builder.build());
        MID++;
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.priya.employeeapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RatingActivity"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.myapp.priya.employeeapp.MyReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the version of android that you installed app?

Comment: My emulator is Nexus 6 API 24

Comment: and if you change the time to 2 minutes ( only to check if is working, because 20 minutes is a long time waiting to see if Works)?

Comment: Yes i put the time 2-3mins from the current time, just to check. But no notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(getApplicationContext());
```

Note: this in your main activity.
Using calendar class is not really accurate.
Start your service in onCreate, then in your receiver class, compare the system time to your required in (24hr format) time, then fire the notification.

```
public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION = "ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION";

    private static final int NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS = 3;

    public static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                getTriggerAt(new Date()),
                20800000,
                alarmIntent);
    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        //calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Intent serviceIntent = null;
        if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive from alarm, starting notification service");
            serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
        } else if (ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive delete notification action, starting notification service to handle delete");
            serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentDeleteNotification(context);
        }

        if (serviceIntent != null) {
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Note :this is in your NotificationEventReceiver,This repeats your notification triggering.

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE = "ACTION_DELETE";
    private Intent mainIntent;

    public NotificationIntentService() {
        super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
        return intent;
    }

    public static Intent createIntentDeleteNotification(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE);
        return intent;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new Date());
               //comparing with required time

                Log.d("noti", "processStartNotification: --"+timeStamp);

                int notableTime = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp);
             //if time matches then fire the method
                if(notableTime>7){

                        processStartNotification();

                    }else
                        {
                            Log.d("noti", "processStartNotification: is halt state > 22" + timeStamp);

                        }

            }
        } finally {
            WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void processDeleteNotification(Intent intent) {
        // Log something?
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void processStartNotification() {
        int ran=new Random().nextInt(4);

        StudentSavedPreferences studentSavedPreferences = new StudentSavedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String Student_id = studentSavedPreferences.getStudentId();
        final Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        int r[]={R.drawable.drip_otification_one,R.drawable.drip_notifications_two,R.drawable.drip_notifications_three,R.drawable.drip_notifications_four};
        String subtext[]={"Give MCQ type test to know about your skill and check your rank.","Watch Video lectures from highly qualified professionals","Get yourself updated by getting daily notifications","Learn even more by all new Audio books and Epub"};
        String from[]={"test","video","notification","epub"};
        if (Student_id == null) {
             mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splashh.class);
                    mainIntent.putExtra("from", "notificationDemo");
                    mainIntent.putExtra("to", from[ran]);

        } else {
            mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainDrawerActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.putExtra("from", "notificationDemo");
                    mainIntent.putExtra("to", from[ran]);
        }
//        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Splashh.class);
//        mainIntent.putExtra("SUBJECT", "MHT-CET");
//        mainIntent.putExtra("Position","0");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                NOTIFICATION_ID,
                mainIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?
        final Bitmap remote_picture_test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), r[ran]);
        final Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.icn_app_icon);
        android.app.Notification notif = new android.app.Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("M-Educate welcomes you the Digital era of learning")
                .setSubText(subtext[ran])
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icn_app_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setStyle(new android.app.Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(remote_picture_test))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notif);

//        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//        builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification")
//                .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbarbackground))
//                .setContentText("This notification has been triggered by Notification Service")
//                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icn_app_icon);
//
//

//        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
//        builder.setDeleteIntent(NotificationEventReceiver.getDeleteIntent(this));
//
//        final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

note: comparing the system time with required time then i fire the method

Comment: wait m sending the snipets

Comment: This the whole code i ve made for same stuff, send in four fragment please let me know if you r getting or not